Word for the act of liking something due to its familiarity
I was drafting an essay and going down the rabbit hole of pressing words on thesaurus.com until the right word I was looking for came up, and I came across this word and used it. Then, my computer crashed and the paragraph I was working on disappeared.
I loved learning this word. I had never came across anything like it.
If it helps, I was discussing in my essay the use of specific language that may be deemed a more advanced in order to convey the intended idea most precisely and effectively, and how my love for this level of language has grown as I have continued to become more accustomed to it.
Anyway, I would say that my love for specific and intentional language grew as I’ve became familiar with it, so this word I’m searching for fits with this idea.
The problem is I can’t remember if I was using it as a verb or adjective. Or maybe even noun??? Please help. I fell in love with the word and can’t find it anywhere.

The phrase 'an easy familiarity' is used, especially but not exclusively for interpersonal relationships.

Oh the ephemeral nature of love! Did it exist, or did you only imagine it? Your experience reads like a film script — perhaps Mizoguchi’s Ugetsu Monogatari.

This really sounds like affinity (definition here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affinity -- specifically refer to definitions 2b and 3a). "Your affinity for this level of language has grown as you have continued to become more accustomed to it."

Also, why not navigate back to your browser history for that day and follow the list of thesaurus results until you find the same page again?

Is acclimate the word you're looking for? Or the adjectives accustomed or attuned or habituated?

@QuackE.Duck also affinity bias

Thanks to everyone who commented. Although affinity does fit this example, I distinctly tememebr the word “familiarity” being in the definition. And it wasn’t accustomed or the similar words mentioned. Maybe I did imagine it, because I did look through my browser history with no luck (it was difficult because I was on my phone though). The word I swear I discovered was almost a combination of affinity and accustomed…

adjectives: cosy, homely/homey/homespun, easy, intimate, informal, natural, unceremonious, chilled, snug, unassuming, heimish; nouns: requiescence, ataraxia, security, and various foreign terms like hygge, Gemütlichkeit.

You could be feeling nostalgic ("longing for or thinking fondly of a past time or condition" - Merriam Webster). This word does not fit precisely, but the 'act of liking something due to its familiarity' indicates that that something evoked nostalgia.

This is a rhetorical question rather than an answer. Could you explain how it would fit into the OP's idea?

@Greybeard I'm not sure why you would find my answer to be rhetorical, I think it is pretty straightforward.

"Could you explain how it would fit into the OP's idea?"
